# Как зациклить скрипт с интервалом.

Tags: python

Пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import GLib as glib

def qwe():
    print 1
    glib.timeout_add_seconds(5, qwe)

qwe()
```

Запускаю скрипт, он пишет один раз в консоль и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое - оформить это в

```
while True:
    qwe()
```

Но тогда будет бесконечно. Если нужно определённое количество раз, то

```
for i in range(10):
    qwe()
```

Извините за оформление, с телефона не удобно.

Интервал можно задать через time sleep()

Comment: Только не range, а xrange.

Comment: Для небольших значений лучше range, отработает быстрее, а памяти займёт не много. Для больших да, xrange.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно запустить event loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gi.repository import GLib, GObject

def qwe():
    print(1)
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(5, qwe)

qwe()
try:
    GObject.MainLoop().run()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # got Ctrl-C
    pass
```

Код, основанный на "event loop", позволяет несколько функций исполнять вперемежку, в отличие от `while True` цикла, который блокирует весь поток:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from time import time as timer

interval = 5
while True:
    time.sleep(interval - timer() % interval)
    print(1)
```

Оба подхода применимы, но в разных обстоятельствах.